# Swiftmail parsing error

Tags: php, email, swiftmailer

I recently moved to Swiftmailer as people have said good things about it. When I used a documentation on how to set it up, I'm getting a strange error. As if their code is wrong.

The error is showing :
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?' in Mailer\classes\Swift\Transport\EsmtpTransport.php on line 211`

I haven't modified this file atoll and it's throwing that error.

I'm calling my username and password from my config file giving them a DEFINE PHP function.

***My code being used is :***

```
    define("AUTHENTICATION_DONOTREDIRECT", 1);
    require("../main_config.php");

    $site_config = new site_config();
    $from = $site_config->grabSiteSettings_manual($con, 'name');

    require 'Mailer/swift_required.php';

    $transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.gmail.com',465,'ssl')->setUserName(gmail_mail)->setPassword(gmail_pass);
    $swift = Swift_Message::newInstance($transport);
    $content = "This is a test message.";

    $message = Swift_Message::newInstance("This is a test email")
    ->setFrom('admin@admin.com')
    ->setTo('benzahdd55@outlook.com')
    ->setBody($content,'text/html')
    ->addPart(strip_tags($content),'text/plain');

    $swift->send($message);

    $myfile = fopen("loggy.txt", "w");
    $txt = "success\n";
    fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    fclose($myfile);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because of the new ?? syntax used in PHP 7. Are you running PHP 5?
You might want to downgrade to an older version or update that line and see if it works.